# iOS: Strange error...UIAlertView not showing...even though it get's called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have no clue where my mistake is...I've used exactly(!) these lines of code in other view controllers of my app and it works. I've set break points and this if is correctly executed and [warning show] is called, however does nothing! This is the firs line (after [super viewWillAppear...) in my viewWillAppear method.

```
if([self.category isDeleted] || ![((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:self.category.objectID error:NULL]){
        UIAlertView *warning = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedError", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedErrorExplanation", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [warning show];
        NSLog(@"%@",warning);
    }
```

The NSLog prints out this:

```
2014-03-11 10:08:08.133 App[752:70b] <UIAlertView: 0x8a8bb20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8aa2d60>>
```

So the object is created..but why doesn't it work? My view controller is also correctly a UIAlertViewDelegate...

Answer (score 0):

The frame is `frame = (0 0; 0 0);` , so you can not see it. Maybe `NSLocalizedString`  return empty string. Try just set title with @"CategoryDeletedError"; if show, check your localized string file in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Got it...just after posting I got the idea. The warning would be shown AFTER my viewWillAppear method. However, there is a line of code calling the deleted entity after this if-clause and crashed the app. So instead of just writing this within and if clause I've solved it like this:

Before:

```
if([self.category isDeleted] || ![((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:self.category.objectID error:NULL]){
        UIAlertView *warning = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedError", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedErrorExplanation", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [warning show];
        NSLog(@"%@",warning);
    }

Rest of the code...crashing
```

Now:

```
if([self.category isDeleted] || ![((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:self.category.objectID error:NULL]){
        UIAlertView *warning = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedError", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedErrorExplanation", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [warning show];
        NSLog(@"%@",warning);
    } else {
       Rest of the code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
if([self.category isDeleted] || ![((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:self.category.objectID error:NULL])
{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   UIAlertView *warning = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedError", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"CategoryDeletedErrorExplanation", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [warning show];
        NSLog(@"%@",warning);
                 });


   }
```